# How to load same view multiple times in a view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, addsubview

Learning swift..so I come across a scenario and not sure of right approach

I have a View controller in which subviews that load depending on the values in the object that is being passed

For eg: Consider a page where the object has name, phone (home, work, mobile), address, birthdate

Now in my view controller, I want to display fields like below picture

[image]

So my model looks like:

```
struct Info {
  let name: String
  let phone: [Phone]
  let address: [Address]
  let bday: String
 }
```

For phones info, i need to loop thru phone array and add views appropriately. If that Phone struct has no mobile info then i dont need to display cell.

So I created XIB file and trying to load that custom view

Also I need to add constraints for "view with Home Phone" to "view with Mobile phone" etc.. so that they are aligned and show like picture above

So my question is

1. How can i add that xib to my viewcontroller

2.Do I have add constraints it manually in code or is there any other way (Can you please gimme a example how i could add same)

If my approach is wrong, please let me know the right way of doing this

Your advice would be more valuable

Comment: Have you checked `UITableview`?

Comment: I agree. It definitely looks like a job for `UITableView`

Comment: I have only one object. I additionaly need to parse the object values to array inorder to display table view. Instead I thought using custom view and resusing same view would be more efficient because I can avoid extra parsing

Comment: if you don't want to more parsing then you can put all value in global variables and then use them accordingly.Here UItableview is best option

Answer (score 1):

Create `UIStackView` in your `xib` or `storyboard`. As stack view has the in-built feature of adjusting view height by its own. Add all your elements(in your case label for name, phone number, etc..) into the `UIStackView` in `vertical` or `horizontal` order as needed. In your controller, just hide the element which you don't need to display for that particular cell. You should have desired view displayed.